# Abstracting Database and Proper Controller Implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture, abstraction

I'm using MongoDB as a backend for my project, but I don't specifically want a dependency on Mongo for the life of the project in case I later decide to change it or in case unit testing is easier without the database. As written, however, my controller is strictly dependent on MongoDB.

Mostly taken from the [MongoDB tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html), I have the following in a `config/initializers/mongo.rb` file.

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost')
MongoMapper.database = 'database'

if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
   PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
     MongoMapper.connection.connect if forked
   end
end
```

In a controller for querying the US states, I have the following code:

```
class StateController < ApplicationController
    def index
        states = MongoMapper.connection.db('database').collection('state').find()

        render :json => states
    end
end
```

There are a few issues I see right off the bat (there are probably more):

1. As previously mentioned, the controller has a hard dependency on MongoDB.
2. I'm not using the `database` property of the MongoMapper class (it's hardcoded in the controller).
3. I don't necessarily want to go through an HTTP endpoint every single time I want a reference to a collection of states --though I'd like to keep this option available. For example, if a signup page has a drop down list for the user to select their home state, it seems foolish to require a client-side jQuery.get() to populate the list of states. It seems to me it would make more sense to have the states pre-fetched server-side and build the drop down list on the server.

For #3, I could certainly query the states in any action method that renders a view that requires the list of states and save them in @states (or something similar), but this would be a lot of duplicate code.

What would be the best way to architect this to allow for less coupling and more code reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should have a Model for states:

```
class State
  include MongoMapper::Document
end
```

Then, in your controller, you should access via that:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :json => State.all
  end
end
```

This way, your controller has no idea what underlying datastore it's using.

Finally, to reduce the need to make a HTTP call, but assuming you're building this in javascript, you code:

```
<div id="#states" data-states="<%= @states.to_json %>"></div>
```

Then load that from `$("#states").data("states")`

Comment: Ahhhh....that makes a lot of sense. I've seen people suggest keeping the controllers as light as possible and for the life of me, I couldn't understand how to query the database without the logic being in the controller. This cleared up a lot. Thank you very much!